# While loop not working as expected to take various cases as input at terminal)

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, while-loop, switch-statement

I am trying to develop my concepts in programming, so i decided to implement queue using linked list.

Probably my logic is correct for both enqueue and dequeue.
But the main reason to ask this question here is that:

(1) I want to read the input at terminal like:

```
Enter 1 to enqueue
Enter 2 to Dequeue
Enter 3 to break
```

For the first time if user press "1" then it will read the value to be enqueued and then enqueue it.

And then the same question is asked at terminal

```
Enter 1 to enqueue
Enter 2 to Dequeue
Enter 3 to break
```

and this way i wanna build linked list which must perform enqueue and dequeue operations and finally can break out when pressed "3".

I have tried to write this procedure of reading the input at terminal in `while loop` with different `if-conditions`. and inside those if conditions i call `enqueue` and `dequeue` functions. 
**The problem is after reading the first value to enqueue it breaks out of the program, I mean i am not able to have the three options "1","2","3" again to "enqueue", "
dequeue" and "break"**.

```
The output is as follows (to explain more):
 Enter 1 to Enqueue 
 Enter 2 to Dequeue 
 Enter 3  to Break
1
Enter the element to be enqueued 
34
hp@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Internship_Xav/Huf_pointer$ //Here it breaks it don't ask again for 3 options.
```

**Could anyone please help me to create a linked list which could do enqueue and dequeue and break on entering "3". (I know it's more about while/switch-case, but i am not able to understand how toimplement that).**

My full code is here : (I have marked the problem creating part in the code)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <malloc.h> 
#include <string.h>
struct node
 {
    int freq;
    struct node * next;
};
typedef struct node node;
node * rear;
node * front;
// Function declarations
void Enqueue(int val);
void dequeue(void);

// Function definitions 
void dequeue() 
{
    node * temp = front;
    if (front == NULL)
    {
        printf("sorry ,The Linked list is empty\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    front = front -> next;
    free(front);
}
 //Function definitions
    void Enqueue(int val) 
    {
        node * temp = (node * ) malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (front == NULL && rear == NULL)
        {
            front = rear = temp;
            return;
        }
        temp -> freq = val;
        temp -> next = NULL;
        rear -> next = temp;
        rear = temp;
    }

    main()
     {
        int ch, val;
    //Problem creating part is below
            while (ch != 3) 
            {
                printf(" Enter 1 to Enqueue \n Enter 2 to Dequeue \n Enter 3  to Break\n");
                scanf("%d", & ch);
                if (ch == 1) 
                {
                    printf("Enter the element to be enqueued \n");
                    scanf("%d", & val);
                    Enqueue(val);
                }
                if (ch == 2) 
                {
                    printf("Trying to Dequeue\n");
                    dequeue();
                }
                if (ch == 1)
                {
                    break;
                } else 
                {
                    printf("Entered wrong choice, Sorry try again\n");
                    return (-1);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part breaks out of the loop.

```
if(ch == 1)
{
    break;
}
```

The first if works fine but since you entered 1 it also runs this if breaking out of the while loop. Also to print out "Entered wrong choice..." it needs to be a series of if else or a switch statement. For example:

```
            if (ch == 1) 
            {
                printf("Enter the element to be enqueued \n");
                scanf("%d", & val);
                Enqueue(val);
            }
            else if (ch == 2) 
            {
                printf("Trying to Dequeue\n");
                dequeue();
            }
            else if(ch == 3)//I assume you meant to put 3
            {
                break;
            }
            else 
            {
                printf("Entered wrong choice, Sorry try again\n");
                return (-1);
            }
```

Here's how I would implement it with if elses though I think a switch would possibly be better but that's more a matter of style in this case.

```
while(ch != 3)
{
    printf(" Enter 1 to Enqueue \n Enter 2 to Dequeue \n Enter 3  to Break\n");
    scanf("%d", & ch);

    //If not 1, 2, or 3 print invalid and go through loop again.
    if(!(ch == 1 || ch == 2 || ch == 3))
    {
        printf("Invalid!!");
    }
    else if(ch == 1)
    {
        printf("Enter the element to be enqueued \n");
        scanf("%d", & val);
        Enqueue(val);
    }
    else if(ch == 2)
    {
        printf("Trying to Dequeue\n");
        dequeue();
    }
    //no need to check for 3 since it will end the loop
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A while back I wrote a small routine to ask questions, called like `menu("E)nqueue D)equeue Q)uit", "edq")`, which returns the selected option or `EOF` if the user terminates input:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int menu(const char *prompt, const char *options)
{
    char c, opt;
    const char *p;

    printf("%s: ", prompt);
    for (;;) {
            while (isspace(c = getchar()))
                    ;
            if (c == EOF) {
                    putchar('\n');
                    return EOF;
            }
            opt = tolower(c);
            while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
                    ;
            for (p = options; *p && opt != tolower(*p); p++)
                    ;
            if (*p)
                    return opt;
            printf("%s: ", options);
    }
}
```

This little routine has seen use in several of my (modest) programs over the years. The idea is to call it e.g. in a `switch()`.

Comment: thanks for the code, Could you please explain in bit more detail that what this code do ? It reads character from terminal if (D,Eand Q) ? and then we can handle them further in switch case ? Right ?

Comment: here is 1 more thing i am working on g++ but it dont support getch (conio.h) otherwise i would have used the same. Any solution for it?